# Is there any way to analyse screen time of individual apps?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package, mobile-application

Is there any package present of flutter to analyse the overall screen time of individual apps of any device

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the IOS, but in android you can use [app usage package](https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage).